# AJAX request returns 403 - access denied, even with folder permissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-component, http-status-code-403

I host my site, https://cameronnelson.net, on Hostinger, and many pages use a custom component I wrote in AJAX / JS that creates an image gallery from a folder of images on the server. It suddenly stopped working (Chrome, Edge, Firefox), without any change to the site on my end... I get a 403 error on any page that tries to use this component to fetch images.

Long-time reader, first-time poster, so I can't post images, but the console output for the error roughly reads:

```
Status
403
Forbidden
VersionHTTP/2
Transferred1.01 kB (699 B size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin

    
cache-control
    private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-length
    699
content-security-policy
    upgrade-insecure-requests
content-type
    text/html
date
    Sat, 12 Nov 2022 16:29:30 GMT
platform
    hostinger
pragma
    no-cache
server
    LiteSpeed
X-Firefox-Spdy
    h2
    
Accept
    */*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection
    keep-alive
Host
    cameronnelson.net
Referer
    https://cameronnelson.net/pages/asphalt.html
Sec-Fetch-Dest
    empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode
    cors
Sec-Fetch-Site
    same-origin
TE
    trailers
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0
X-Requested-With
    XMLHttpRequest
```

This is the code for the component, "gallery.js:"

```
class Gallery extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
  
    connectedCallback() {

        this.innerHTML = `
        <div class='card-columns' id='gallery_header' style='column-count:1;'></div>
        <div class='card-columns'>
        <div id='gallery'></div>
        </div>
        `;

        var src = this.getAttribute('src');
        var title = this.getAttribute('title');
        var text = this.getAttribute('text');

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url : src,
                success: function (data) {

                    if((title != null) || (text != null)) {
                        var title_card = `
                        <div class='card'>
                            <div class='card-body' style='text-align:justify'>`
                            + (title != null ? `<div class='card-title'>` + title + `</div>`:'')
                            + (text != null ? `<div class='card-text'>` + text + `</div>`:'')
                            + `</div>
                        `;
                        $("#gallery_header").append( title_card );
                    }

                    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                        if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {
                            var card = `
                            <div class='card clickable'>
                            <a data-fancybox='gallery' href='`+ val + `'>
                                <img class='card-img-top' src='`+ val + `'/>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            `;
                            $("#gallery").append( card );
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            
        });

    }
  }
  
  customElements.define('gallery-component', Gallery);
```

I checked permissions for the folder (e.g. public_html/images/[subfolder]), and "read" is turned on for all users. Just to test I checked off all boxes, read/write/execute, for all users, and the problem persisted. Everything works when testing on a local server. I've read online it could be an issue with .htaccess but I never created an .htaccess file for this site. I tried making a version of the page(s) using php instead of js, but it also returned 403. Could it be a change to Hostinger's servers? I reached out to their staff but they seemed to be unaware of any changes that would cause this, so I'm not sure how to continue... any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend looking into this error first: `Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.` 
Also the request for the resource ends with a slash (`https://cameronnelson.net/images/artifakts/`), I don't know much about Hostinger but it could be they think you're trying to request a directory which a lot of hosting providers don't like

Comment: Second look, when on the overview the website is requesting `https://cameronnelson.net/images/artifakts/10-3.jpg` where as the actual artifakts page is requesting that resource without the filename i.e. `https://cameronnelson.net/images/artifakts/`. Not sure if this is intended but could be a lead for you

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I am requesting the directory and then the code should auto-detect all files of type jpeg, gif, etc... and then build a gallery dynamically. You're right that I can access images directly, like https://cameronnelson.net/images/asphalt/glyph1.png, but accessing the whole directory returns 403. To make the code work I need the entire directory, though, because I don't know all the filenames beforehand. The jQuery/Bootstrap error occurs also on other pages that are working properly, like pages/cholla.html, so I don't think that's the cause.

Comment: Since it is working locally I would assume it has something to do with the way hostinger has things set up. If there isn't already an `.htaccess` file, try creating on in the artifakts directory and add this `Allow from All`. Save the file and see if the directory is accessible. If it isn't, try setting the folder permissions to 0777 (very bad practice but permissible while setting things up). If that also doesn't work I'd try contacting hostinger directly.

Comment: Ah, yes I tried 0777 without luck, and neither did adding "Allow from All" in an .htaccess file (tried placing in root, images, and artifakts directories). I reached out to Hostinger before but I don't think they knew what was going on. I'll try reaching out to them again! Thanks for the help.